# How to create temporary class?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'd like to create a temporary class without having to build the concrete class.  The workflow will look like this:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
myList.Add(new() {prop1 = 33, prop2 = "test"});
myList.Add(new() {prop1 = 35, prop2 = "test2"});
```

//loop through myList, accessing both properties of each list item

Any ideas how something like that can be done?

Comment: Have you created the object already? Or do you want to create it?

Comment: It will be created on the fly, as shown in the Add() methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = CreateList(new { prop1 = 33, prop2 = "test" });
        myList.Add(new {prop1 = 35, prop2 = "test2"});

        foreach (var entry in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.prop1);
            Console.WriteLine(entry.prop2);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] elements)
    {
        return new List<T>(elements);
    }
```

Comment: Since this is a "var", would I still need List<object>?

Comment: That works great.  Although I didn't create the List<T>.  I just used object.  Any difference in using "dynamic" vs "var" in the loop?  Or just replacing all "var" with "dynamic"?

Comment: `var` and `dynamic` do **very** diffrent things. Unless you are working with COM interop, you should almost *NEVER* be using `dynamic`. Most problems that people want to use `dynamic` on would be better fixed by fixing the source that required you to use dynamic in the first place.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Where did you get that restriction?  That certainly isn't what Microsoft has to say http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx.

Comment: The dynamic keyword removes the type checking, so if you make a mistake, you'll find out at runtime.  The var keyword implies the actual type, so errors are caught at compile time.  Notice you can type "entry." and the IDE will list prop1 and prop2.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a concrete type, however if you really want, you can use dynamic with anonymous types to keep access to the properties.

```
List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>();
myList.Add(new {prop1 = 33, prop2 = "test"});
myList.Add(new {prop1 = 35, prop2 = "test2"});
foreach(dynamic obj in myList) {
    Console.WriteLine(obj.prop1);
}
```

But I can't really say what you gain by doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The thing stopping you accessing the members currently is the `object`. You could perhaps type it as an array of the anonymous type:

```
var arr = new[] {
    new { foo = 123, bar = "abc" },
    new { foo = 456, bar = "def" }
};
foreach(var row in arr) {
     Console.WriteLine(row.foo);
     Console.WriteLine(row.bar);
}
```

If you need to add rows flexibly, then there are tricks to allow that (basically using an example item to exploit compiler type-inference, to create an empty list of the anonymous-type): but to be honest you'd be a lot better off just declaring a class and using that.